# SonarQube 6.0 doesn't find project on TFS 2015

Tags: tfs, sonarqube, tfs-2015, msbuild-task

I have a ASP.Net Web Application using .Net Framework 4.5.1 and it's building on the TFS Buildserver (on premise), but SonarQube doesn't perform the analysis. All other buildsteps are successfull. SonarQube 6.0 is a fresh installation, the Runner was installed around a year ago.
The necessary .Net Frameworks for SonarQube and Builds are installed on the build machine.

On a WebAPI Project the analyzer works like a charm. What could it be?

```
******************************************************************************
Starting task: Fetch the Quality Profile from SonarQube
******************************************************************************
Executing the powershell script: C:\Agents\Agent1\tasks\SonarQubePreBuild\1.0.34\SonarQubePreBuild.ps1
SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild 1.1
Default properties file was not found at C:\Agents\Agent1\tasks\SonarQubePreBuild\1.0.34\MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner-1.1\SonarQube.Analysis.xml
Pre-processing started.
Preparing working directories...
Checking for updates...
SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild Begin Step 2.1
14:41:58.919  Default properties file was not found at C:\Agents\Agent1\_work\14\.sonarqube\bin\SonarQube.Analysis.xml
14:41:58.929  Updating build integration targets...
14:41:58.939  Fetching analysis configuration settings...
14:41:59.039  Generating rulesets...
14:42:00.119  Provisioning analyzer assemblies...
14:42:00.119  Installing required Roslyn analyzers...
Pre-processing succeeded.
******************************************************************************
Finishing task: SonarQubePreBuild
******************************************************************************
```

... building solution, publish symbols & drop ...

```
******************************************************************************
Starting task: Finish the analysis and upload the results to SonarQube
******************************************************************************
Executing the powershell script: C:\Agents\Agent1\tasks\SonarQubePostTest\1.0.36\SonarQubePostTest.ps1
SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild 1.1
Default properties file was not found at C:\Agents\Agent1\tasks\SonarQubePreBuild\1.0.34\MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner-1.1\SonarQube.Analysis.xml
Post-processing started.
SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild End Step 2.1
14:40:50.486  WARNING: Failed to find the code coverage command line tool. Possible cause: Visual Studio is not installed, or the installed version does not support code coverage.
The exclude flag has been set so the project will not be analyzed by SonarQube. Project file: C:\Agents\Agent1\_work\14\s\TdbWeb\TdbWeb\TdbWeb.csproj
No analysable projects were found. SonarQube analysis will not be performed. Check the build summary report for details.
Generation of the sonar-properties file failed. Unable to complete SonarQube analysis.
14:40:50.526  Creating a summary markdown file...
Post-processing failed. Exit code: 1
Unexpected exit code received from batch file: 1
The build was not set to fail if the associated quality gate fails.
******************************************************************************
Finishing task: SonarQubePostTest
******************************************************************************
```

Comment: Did you install .NET Framework v4.5.2+ ? According to http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/From+Team+Foundation+Server+2015+or+Visual+Studio+Team+Services, .NET Framework v4.5.2+ is required.

Comment: Yes, .Net Framework v4.5.2, v4.6 and v4.6.1 and VS Pro 15 Update 2 is installed on the build machine.

Comment: Could you double confirm your application is a Web Application Solutions or Web Site Solutions?

Comment: It's a Web Application Solution. I think I started with the MVC Template, but could also be the Empty template.

Answer (score 0):

You need Visual Studio Enterprise edition for code coverage and you are using VS Pro. Have a look at [this page](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/compare/) and expand the 'tesing tools' section. Code coverage is only listed for the Enterprise edition.

Comment: I'm using dotCover to get code coverage, do I still need VS Enterprise? Can I/how do I tell sonarqube to not use VS code coverage and just use the report I provide from dotCover?